# preg_match_all skip node parts

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to run a filter on some packets. To receive the informations I need.

---

I'm using PHP `preg_match_all` to run my filter and to find any match.

---

Sadly the packet does contain different nodes.

```
<u i='550820' m='0'>
    <n>
        <![CDATA[supers0nic-]]>
    </n>
    <vars>
        <var n='state' t='s'>
        <![CDATA[0]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationX' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[490.75]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationY' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[201.5]]>
        </var>
        <var n='zchievements' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[684]]>
        </var>
    </vars>
</u>

<u i='550946' m='0'>
    <n>
        <![CDATA[cutie_lexi12]]>
    </n>
    <vars>
        <var n='destinationX' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[249.9]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationY' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[323.34999999999997]]>
        </var>
        <var n='zchievements' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[12731]]>
        </var>
    </vars>
</u>
```

---

Here's an example of what im trying to receive. Important is replaced with NEEDTHIS:

```
<u i='NEEDTHIS' m='0'>
    <n>
        <![CDATA[NEEDTHIS]]>
    </n>
    <vars>
        <var n='state' t='s'>
        <![CDATA[0]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationX' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[NEEDTHIS]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationY' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[NEEDTHIS]]>
        </var>
        <var n='zchievements' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[684]]>
        </var>
    </vars>
</u>
```

Sadly i have to skip some parts in the node like the following code:

```
<var n='state' t='s'>
    <![CDATA[0]]>
</var>
```

Because this isn't contained in every node.

---

My actual code:

```
\<u i=\'([0-9]+)\' m=\'0\'\>\<n\>\<\!\[CDATA\[([a-z0-9\-\_\s]+)\]\]\>\<\/n\>\<vars\>\<var n=\'state\' t=\'s\'\>\<\!\[CDATA\[0\]\]>\<\/var\>\<var n=\'destinationX\' t=\'n\'\>\<\!\[CDATA\[([0-9\.]+)]\]\>\<\/var\>\<var n=\'destinationY\' t=\'n\'\>\<\!\[CDATA\[([0-9\.]+)]\]\>\<\/var\>\<var n=\'zchievements\' t=\'n\'\>\<\!\[CDATA\[([0-9]+)\]\]\>\<\/var\>\<\/vars\>\<\/u\>
```

---

So I need to **skip** the

```
<var n='state' t='s'>
    <![CDATA[0]]>
</var>
```

and

```
<var n='zchievements' t='n'>
    <![CDATA[684]]>
</var>
```

part.

---

How would I realize this?

Comment: why not just do it right and use an xml parser? That is what they are made for. And there are simple ones built right into php.

Comment: Cause we receive tons of packets and the connection of the bot have to stay alive. And we have to search for this specific match. Its made for a bot.

Comment: Why does it being "a bot" matter whether you use a regex or an xml parser. If it is still PHP, there wouldn't be a difference as far as the bot is concerned.

Comment: Here, while I am completely against it, this works: https://regex101.com/r/jF4iG6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). You can access the parsed XML in an object/tree like fashion.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<'JUSTUSEXML'
<u i='550820' m='0'>
    <n>
        <![CDATA[supers0nic-]]>
    </n>
    <vars>
        <var n='state' t='s'>
        <![CDATA[0]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationX' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[490.75]]>
        </var>
        <var n='destinationY' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[201.5]]>
        </var>
        <var n='zchievements' t='n'>
            <![CDATA[684]]>
        </var>
    </vars>
</u>
JUSTUSEXML;

// LIBXML_NOCDATA lets you access the CDATA tags.
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
print_r($nodes);

foreach ($nodes->vars as $varList) {
    foreach ($varList as $vars) {
        $var = trim($vars[0]);
        echo $var . "\n";
    }
}
```

Jonathan Kuhn is right. Use an XML parser to parse XML. Filtering or simply ignoring what you don't need should be much easier that way.